# How can a certain git repository state be kept always accessible?

Tags: svn, git, tags, workflow

I am trying to devise rules for a small group of people collaborating on software that is used for data analysis. It is important to have a means to reproduce the running of the code at some point in the past, i.e. to revert to a state in the past (something that version control should allow). In the past this has been possible for us with svn. We can then tag our data analysis results with the svn revision number used for that run.

There are [stories](http://randyfay.com/node/89) about how through branching, merging and rebasing, histories are lost/made inaccessible/a nightmare to get to etc. At the same time, the easy handling of branching for experimental feature development is what makes us consider a switch from svn to git.

So: What rules should we follow that would make sure we will easily and always be able to retrieve a state of code that was run for a given analysis? Only use the main branch for analysis runs? If so what operations should be disallowed on the main branch?

EDIT: Two good suggestions are explained below: Tagging of commits that are important will make the analysis transparent and reproducible (antlersoft). This requires no new rules other than to leave the tags in peace. This tagging workflow does not require rules for rebasing and merging. Tom Anderson's suggestion is useful in that a central repo that is supposed to house all code that has tags attached (this would be a convention/rule) could serve to allow other members access to these bits of code.

Comment: Git is more powerful in these aspects than SVN, but maybe people get confused or due to ignorance mess up the repo ( I have done the same many times, learned a lot, but still manage to do it at times. Git is powerful, yes, and has a huge learning curve )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this doesn't have to involve restricting what you can do on any branch.  Just use git tags, and don't remove or move them. Tag the commit you use to run each analysis, and record the commit tag with the analysis (this is very similar with what you do in svn, except instead of a revision number generated by the VCS it is a tag name you supply).  Then the version for the analysis and all its history will always be available, regardless of what else you do (rebase, etc.) on the branch.

Comment: What happens if you make a commit, tag that commit, then rebase that commit to some other place? Does the tag move? If so, then if the rebase changes the behaviour of the code (which it will, by merging it with other commits), then the behaviour marked by the tag has changed. Or do tags stop you doing that?

Comment: No. The tag keeps the old commits where they were. The rebase ends up copying them to the new place. Another branch will also stay there. Rebasing is not as bad as people make it out to be. You just have to understand how git works and keep published commits published.

Comment: @Tom Anderson Rebasing does not remove history; once an object is created in git it can't be changed.  You can lose track of it if there is no reference to it.  Rebasing a branch changes the head of the branch to a commit with a different history than the commit before the rebase, so the commit before the rebase can't be found on the branch.  However, the commit before the rebase is still in the repository; you can get to it from the reflog or if it's tagged, it can still be found from the tag.

Comment: @antlersoft: aha, so my suspicion that it's all still there no matter what was right. And to make sure it will always be easily accessible I will have to tag commits and become immune to interference from subsequent rebase and merges, correct?

Comment: @DrSAR -- Yes, a tagged commit will stay accessible and unchanged regardless of what happens to the branch the commit started on.

Comment: I don't think it has been explicitly mentioned yet: if you rebase, old commits stay in the repo only until they get garbage collected.  Putting a tag on a commit prevents it from being garbage collected.  It also makes the commit easier to find.

Answer (score 2):

The only rule you would need to follow is to never delete history. That means never rebasing, or using a few other, less common operations.

Rather, it means never rebasing (etc) in the repository from which you run your analyses. People can rebase freely in other repositories. Would it be possible for you to set up a 'golden master' repository, to which everyone pushes code, with a no-rebase policy, and use that to run your analyses? People can then develop code however they like locally, and push to that repository when ready to run. That's a fairly normal workflow for teams using a DVCS.

If people need to run analyses (for publication, as it were) from their local repositories, then things are trickier. I'd suggest that everyone have two repositories locally, one for development, and one for doing analysis. Rebasing is allowed in the development repository, but code must be pushed to the analysis repository to be used (and then on to the rest of the team). That's a little weaker, because it's only convention that stops people rebasing in the analysis repository, whereas with a central repository which nobody uses directly, rebasing just isn't something that will happen.

Comment: This sounds feasible: I could have a golden master. However, people will still run local analysis from local repositories. Instead of two local repos, could one have two branches + conventions? Also, are there git configs to enforce the no rebase rule for a repo?

Comment: Git will run a pre-rebase hook before rebasing; if that hook fails, the rebase is aborted. If you wanted to ban rebasing altogether, you could use /bin/false as the hook. You could also ban rebasing selectively in local repositories. You could use @antlersoft's idea, tag everything you use for an analysis, then abort any rebase which would move a tagged commit (somehow!). You might also be able to do something about testing if a given commit has been pushed to the master already (maybe looking at the position of the tracked branch head?) and reject rebases of already-pushed commits.

Comment: rebase to your hearts content. Just make a tag or branch to track where those commits were so they're available for everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old but I just want to make one thing clear...
Rebasing doesn't delete any history, and doesn't delete any commits. It only adds new commits and move a branch ref.
As long as a commit is referenced by anything (branch, tag or other commit) it will live on forever.
Only unreferenced objects are deleted if they are old (think it is 30 days by default) and you do a garbage collection or similar.